# How To make a challenge request in Facebook game

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-requests

I'm pretty new in using the facebook SDK.

I have kind of a racin app in facebook and I want to challenge other friends. Also friends which have not installed the app.

I read on the facebook developer page

> Match Making
>
> Keep in mind that requests can be sent to any player that has already
>   installed the game;

But to reach more users I want to send challenge request also to any of my users in my friendlist.

Do I have to send those people which haven't installed the app an app request instead?

Does anybody have some experience with match making games in facebook? Maybe a nice tutorial on the web? The FB Doc for me is very superficial.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On what page did you read that? requests can be sent to any users even if they don't use the app - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

Comment: You can have users send requests to another user that is not already connected to your app – but then that request will be considered an _invite_ – the page Igy linked describes what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Import FacebookSDK in your application and Use below code.

```
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
       message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just smashed %d friends! Can you beat it?", nScore]
       title:@"Smashing!" parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
       {
             if (error) 
             {
                    // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                    NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
             } else 
             {
                    if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                        // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                        NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                    }
             }}
             friendCache:nil];
        }
```